# Remote debug Alfresco 4.0 in Tomcat as win service

Tags: windows, debugging, tomcat, service, alfresco

I have to do some remote debug of [Alfresco 4.0](http://www.alfresco.com/) in Tomcat_6.0.35. [The Offical documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/debug-installation.html) say that I should set env variable

> JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,
>   address=8082

and I did it, but it works only with startup.bat . Alfresco 4.0 start Tomcat as windows service and call this:

> C:\Alfresco\tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe //RS//alfrescoTomcat

So I need to do remote debug of this servise and I try to change default service invoke of Tomcat to:

> 1) c:\Alfresco\tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe //RS//alfrescoTomcat
>   --JvmOptions=-Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8082;

or

> 2) c:\Alfresco\tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe //TS//alfrescoTomcat
>   --JvmOptions=-Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8082;

It successfuly starts Tomcat and I can debug this server, but Alfresco 4.0 throw exception or hangs...what should I do for debug this service?

my log:

> Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8082
>   11.04.2012 19:13:28 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.20.
>   11.04.2012 19:13:28 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters
>   [false], random [true].
>   11.04.2012 19:13:28 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
>   11.04.2012 19:13:28 org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
>   11.04.2012 19:13:29 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8443
>   11.04.2012 19:13:29 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization processed in 1145 ms
>   11.04.2012 19:13:29 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start INFO: Starting service Catalina
>   11.04.2012 19:13:29 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
>   11.04.2012 19:13:29 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor alfresco.xml
>   11.04.2012 19:13:30 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener INFO: The listener
>   "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already
>   configured for this context. The duplicate definitio n has been
>   ignored.
>   11.04.2012 19:13:32 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
>
> ...
>
> e.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
>   e.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>   e.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>   e.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>   e.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>   e.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>   e.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>   ct.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ct.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   ct.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   .reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   e.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>   e.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   gframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
>   with name 'transactionService' defined in class path
>   core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transacti xception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager' h resource
>   [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'sessionFactory' while setting bean proper  nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFact s path resource
>   [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.Hi bernate Dialect must be
>   explicitly set
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:10
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFacto
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>
> gframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
>   with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path
>   hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class
>   esco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hib be explicitly set
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:10
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFacto
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>
> gframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
>   with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path res
>   rnate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception
>   is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Di itly set
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>
> nate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
>   nate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:59)
>   nate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
>   nate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:426)
>   nate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
>   nate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2073)
>   nate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1298)
>   gframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
>   gframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
>   gframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
>
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart nding context
>   initialized event to listener instance of class
>   org.alfresco.web.app.ContextListener
>   beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name
>   'encryptionKeysRegistry' defined in class path resour
>   ion-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'transactionService' while setting bean property 'transactionService'
>   s org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionService' defined in 
>   [alfresco/core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'transactionManager' while setting bean property '; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transacti n class path resource
>   [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'sessionFactory' while setting onFactory'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name ' ned in class path resource
>   [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is org.h ception: Hibernate Dialect must be
>   explicitly set
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:10
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFacto
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580
>
> gframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:89
>
> gframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>   gframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>   gframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>   gframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>   sco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
>   e.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
>   e.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
>   e.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
>   e.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
>   e.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
>   e.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
>   e.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
>   e.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>   e.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>   e.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>   e.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>   e.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>   ct.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   ct.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   ct.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   .reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   e.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>   e.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   gframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
>   with name 'transactionService' defined in class path
>   core-services-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'transactionManager' while setting bean property 'transacti xception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'transactionManager' h resource
>   [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'sessionFactory' while setting bean proper  nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFact s path resource
>   [alfresco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is org.hibernate.Hi bernate Dialect must be
>   explicitly set
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:10
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFacto
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>
> gframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
>   with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path
>   hibernate-context.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean
>   'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class
>   esco/hibernate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested
>   exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hib be explicitly set
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:10
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFacto
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>
> gframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean
>   with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path res
>   rnate-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception
>   is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Hibernate Di itly set
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:4
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
>
> nate.HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set
>   nate.dialect.DialectFactory.determineDialect(DialectFactory.java:59)
>   nate.dialect.DialectFactory.buildDialect(DialectFactory.java:39)
>   nate.cfg.SettingsFactory.determineDialect(SettingsFactory.java:426)
>   nate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:128)
>   nate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2073)
>   nate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1298)
>   gframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:860)
>   gframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:779)
>   gframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
>   gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory
>
> gframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.ja
>
> com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
>   contextInitialized AX-WS context listener initializing
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate  AX-WS
>   servlet initializing org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   erStart org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start fresco] startup
>   failed due to previous errors
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate destroy AX-WS
>   servlet destroyed
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener
>   contextDestroyed AX-WS context listener destroyed
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log  root
>   WebApplicationContext org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
>   log4j org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearThreadLocalMap
>   ication [/alfresco] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [null]
>   (value [com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ClassFactory$1@2552fafd])
>   [java.util.WeakHashMap] (value [{class
>   javax.xml.bind.annotation.W3CDomHandler=java.lang.ref.WeakReference@5bee9e20}])
>   b it when the web application was stopped. This is very likely to
>   create a memory leak. org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
>   clearThreadLocalMap ication [/alfresco] created a ThreadLocal with key
>   of type [java.lang.ThreadLocal] (value [java.lang.ThreadLocal@ecf7607
>   pe [org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl] (value
>   [org.apache.cxf.bus.CXFBusImpl@564dcd29]) but failed to remove it when
>   the web pped. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
>   ger.repositorySelector was null likely due to error in class
>   reloading, using NOPLoggerRepository. vocationTargetException

Comment: They key line in the exception is **HibernateException: Hibernate Dialect must be explicitly set** - are you sure you're not changing anything else when you start Alfresco in debug, as it looks like you are loosing your database settings with your change...

Comment: Yes, my command line parameters were wrong. When parameter is prefixed with "--" previous settings are removed. If I use prefix "++", previous settings saved and everything is working correctly. So with call: "C:\Alfresco\tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe //RS//alfrescoTomcat ++JvmOptions "-Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"" all works correctly :) thanks!

Comment: You should probably post this as an answer and accept it, then it's clearer to people coming later that the problem is solved and what the trick is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, my command line parameters were wrong. When parameter is prefixed with "**--**" previous settings are removed. If I use prefix "**++**", previous settings saved and everything is working correctly. So with call:

> C:\Alfresco\tomcat\bin\tomcat6.exe //RS//alfrescoTomcat ++JvmOptions
>   "-Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000"

all works correctly :) thanks!